# Assert messages for sap.ui.core.Icon `src`

Tags: sapui5

I would like to use:

```xml
<core:Icon src="{path: 'STATUS', formatter: '.formatter.getTableStatusIcon'}" />
```

But I get this error when I use it:

> Element sap.ui.core.Icon#__icon0-__clone600: Property 'src' (value: '') should be a valid Icon URI (sap-icon://...)

Comment: Did the below answer help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. But I tried another solution.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the answer below if the solution is related to the question. One of the answers should be accepted to let others know that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an empty string, return `null`.

```js
getTableStatusIcon: function(status) {
  // ...
  return null; // default value of the Icon src
},
```

Or in case of an expression binding in XML view:

```xml
<core:Icon src="{= <my condition> ? ${myIconUri} : null}" />
```

This won't trigger the `assert` message because `null` and `undefined` are used for resetting Control's property value (i.e.: no icon), which I assume you were trying to do by passing an empty string.

The message was first introduced in 1.56 in order to discourage developers from assigning the icon name only (e.g. `"edit"` instead of `"sap-icon://edit"`):

> Although it is not mentioned in the API, the 'src' property also
> accepted a[n] icon name of the default collection as value instead of the
> documented Icon URI (IconPool.getIconURI).
> This is was caused by 867c4c6 and works
> again, but is still not recommended. Therefore an assertion is added.  [(Source)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/9e94621da9c3a94babe86af468260d72957dc532)